# How do I open the "Save As" dialog box in Outlook using VSTO and get the user entered filename

Tags: outlook, vsto, openfiledialog, save-as

I'm creating a VSTO add-in for Outlook. As part of this add-in, I need to be able to allow the user the save a grid as a CSV file. When the user clicks on the "Export" button on the grid, I want to pop up the "Save as" dialog box, allow the user to select a file/enter a file name and location. When the user clicks ok, I need a way for my add-in to gain control again, get the file location entered and use that to write my CSV into.

I've been looking around for some time now, but I just can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Just figured out that the answer is right here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221287/using-the-openfiledialog-control-in-a-c-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SaveFileDialog like in the answer here: [Using the OpenFileDialog control in a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221287/using-the-openfiledialog-control-in-a-c-application)